# SAGA Slope Stability algorithms missing in QGIS 2.18.11

Tags: qgis, saga

I have install `QGIS 2.18.11` via OSGEO4W 64 bit (that programs and versions install with QGIS `SAGA` version `2.3.2` `GRASS` version `7.2.1`).
I can use SAGA algorithms without problem in QGIS using `processing toolbar` but not all algorithms from this SAGA version.
If I use SAGA stand-alone, I can use the terrain analysis `Slope Stability` toolbar. That toolbar has six SAGA algorithms.

Why are algorithms from this toolbar missing from the Processing toolbox?

Is it possible to add these algorithms manually?

Answer (score 1):

It is not a problem in the installation of QGIS 2.18.11 and version 2.3.2 on your machine, but actually not all SAGA tools existing in SAGA standalone program are integrated in QGIS SAGA processing tools. There are many tools in SAGA standalone program such as slope stability (completely not included), Lighting (3 tools in QGIS, but 7 tools in SAGA software), and many others which are very useful and not integrated in QGIS processing tools.

Maybe it is not a convenient way, but the easiest route you can follow is to work with both software to get the results you want. This is the way I do if I need to work with a SAGA tool that does not exist in QGIS processing toolbox.

Integrating all SAGA tools in QGIS may require to do some python programming as there is a python wrapper located in `C:\Program Files\QGIS2.18\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing\algs\saga` if you download the QGIS installer (thanks to AndreJ for pointing that), or in `C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing\algs\saga` if you download QGIS from OSGeo4W. Therefore, it will be a lengthy process if you want to do it by yourself.

Comment: Are you sure about the `C++ programming`? As far as I know, the wrappers in `C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing\algs\saga` are written in Python.

Comment: @AndreJ thanks for your comment. I am not sure about C++, but if there is a wrapper for python that can integrate additional SAGA tool, I think it will be easier. Anyway, I will update my answer.

Comment: @ahmadhanb I use pyqgis I have built some plugins but your details is wrong if I `print processing.alglist()` then I don't get names of this algorithms where I want

Comment: @jessiejes my details are not wrong. When you use `print processing.alglist()` you actually print what exists in the processing toolbox, and since the tool that you want does not exist, you do not get anything. I am saying that the python wrapper may help you to write your own script to include additional SAGA tools into processing toolbox. However, I am not sure if that can work either.  There might be some reasons why OSGeo4W team did not add all tools of SAGA into processing toolbox, which I do not have knowledge about.

Comment: @ahmadhanb ok sorry I understand,can you tell how to fix that using python ?you have some idea ?

Comment: @jessiejes actually I do not know how you can do it using python. As I mentioned in my I usually work with SAGA standalone if the tool that I need is not included in QGIS processing. Then I continue my work in QGIS.